# Running an Oozie job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, oozie

I'm trying to configure Oozie to work on my hadoop-2.7.1 cluster. Everything seems to work fine, YARN, Hue, MapReduce and Spark. Jobs send by `yarn jar...` command finish correctly, but sending some job with oozie, either by CLI `oozie job ... -run` or by Hue, the job is stuck at 33% and node logs show this:

```
2015-11-06 06:08:56,121 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:18030
2015-11-06 06:08:57,165 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:18030. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
...
```

I don't use 18030 port anywhere in my configuration, probably I should change its hostname from `localhost` to the network hostname. But where do I configure it? I've tried to change `yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address`, but that wasn't it.

**EDIT:**
I run `oozie job  -config examples/apps/shell/job.properties -run` with `job.properties` containing:

```
nameNode=hdfs://master:8020
jobTracker=master:8032
queueName=default
examplesRoot=examples
oozie.libpath=/data/shared/hadoop-2.7.1/etc/hadoop

oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/apps/shell
```

Comment: Your post gives absolutely **no insight** about what you have submitted to Oozie server, so the bounty is kind of useless.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Anything, including example jobs. It just doesn't work.

Comment: Useful info would be: content of parameters file if any (cf. `-config`), Workflow script and especially the XMLschema version & the `<job-tracker>` element (in `<global>` section and/or in each `<action>`)

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter There are plenty of examples [here](https://github.com/apache/oozie/tree/master/examples/src/main/apps). Only changes are made inside `job.properties` file (both locally and on hdfs, even hdfs side shouldn't matter).

Comment: "The gap between theory and practise is wider in practise". I'm not interested in what you **think** you did. Just show what you **actually** did, *as seen by Oozie*, i.e. `oozie job -configcontent sample-job-id` and `oozie job -definition sample-job-id` (or the equivalent tabs in Hue console)

Comment: @swish can you  post your yarn-site.xml here.

Answer (score 1):

The error is occurring while trying to contact the Resource Manager.

The above mentioned log line is being printed in RMProxy.java:

```
LOG.info("Connecting to ResourceManager at " + rmAddress);
```

When you are using Oozie with MRv1, in "job.properties" file, the value of **jobTracker** is set to the Job Tracker's address:

> jobTracker={JobTracker Host}:{JobTracker Port}

But, when you migrate your Oozie job to MRv2, you need to change "job.properties", to make **jobTracker** value to point to Resource Manager address:

> jobTracker={RM Host}:{RM Port}

Please refer to the link here: https://support.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/203355837-How-to-run-a-MapReduce-jar-using-Oozie-workflow

```
jobTracker = Variable to define the resource manager address in case of Yarn implementation. Format: <resourcemanager_hostname>:<port>
```

**EDIT:**
I went through the Hadoop source code. The only place where port "18030" is being used is in "SLS" (Yarn Scheduler Load Simulator).

SLS has a yarn-site.xml file (present at location: \hadoop-tools\hadoop-sls\src\main\sample-conf\yarn-site.xml), which has following configuration:

```
  <property>
    <description>The address of the scheduler interface.</description>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>localhost:18030</value>
  </property>
```

From your description, it seems the yarn-site.xml that is being used, is similar to the one used by SLS.

Comment: OK. Then you need to check why it is trying to connect to port 18030 on localhost. It should resolve to the RM host IP.

Comment: This is the main problem. I don't know where this port is configured or what property this is.

Comment: Can you check the value of this property in yarn-site.xml: "yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address"?

Comment: Yes. I have read your question :). I know that you tried changing this property. I just wanted to confirm. Since this value by default is set to 8030, I felt it is one of the ports which could have been set to 18030. Let me check my configurations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94598/discussion-between-swish-and-manjunath-ballur).